# Concatenate array of strings, and prepending another string with F#

Tags: string, f#, concatenation

I have a string array lines, for example

```
lines = [| "hello"; "world" |]
```

I'd like to make a string line that concatenates the elements in lines with "code=" string prepended. For example, I need to get the string `code="helloworld"` from the lines array.

I could get the concatenated string with this code

```
let concatenatedLine = lines |> String.concat ""
```

And I tested this code to prepend "code=" string as follows, but I got `error FS0001: The type 'string' is not compatible with the type 'seq<string>'` error.

```
let concatenatedLine = "code=" + lines |> String.concat ""
```

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`+` binds stronger than `|>`, so you need to add some parentheses:

```
let concatenatedLine = "code=" + (lines |> String.concat "")
```

Otherwise the compiler parses the expression like:

```
let concatenatedLine = (("code=" + lines) |> (String.concat ""))
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                         error FS0001
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to try the following ( forward piping operator has lower precedence)

```
let concatenatedLine = "code=" + (lines |> String.concat "" )
```